# What does 蕉 mean in Cantonese?

Tags: meaning, topolect

I've seen 蕉 translated into Mandarin (and dubbed into Mandarin) as 肏.

[CC-CANTO](http://cccanto.org/) doesn't really give anything much for [蕉](http://cccanto.org/search.php?q=%E8%95%89) in Cantonese.

[words.hk](http://words.hk/zidin/%E8%95%89) doesn't give any results, either.

I'm guessing 蕉 just fits the pronunciation `ziu1` but is not the actual character for whatever it is supposed to mean, but I have no way of knowing for sure.

- What does 蕉 mean in Cantonese?

Comment: It means 'banana' literally. But it can be used as swear words for its shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it means bananas (香蕉)! But if people say "食蕉" to you in a foul way, it means "eat shit", because a banana and shit are similar in shape i guess...

i am from HK and i speak Cantonese
.

Comment: Doesn't 食蕉 mean something to do with fellatio?

Comment: that usage is also possible but relatively rare in my life experience

Answer (score 1):

if people say "食蕉" to you in a foul way, it means "suck dick" and not eat shit!